# Why do I get, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined" in this simple Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, typeerror, meteor-blaze

I'm following along with the tutorial [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates) and, after adding the html and JavaScript to replace the default markup/code, I get, "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined*"

Here is my HTML, straight from the tut:

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

...and here is my JavaScript, also straight from the tut:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is task 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });
}
```

All I see on the page is the h1 ("Todo List").

What is wrong, and how to rectify?

Comment: As a follow-up, the code above (from Meteor tutorial, https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates)  does work with meteor v1.1. 

I ran into the same error running an older version of meteor (v1.0). After updating, the code ran fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I answered without looking closely at your markup. Try the following:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    {{> tasks}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="tasks">
  <ul>
    {{#each tasks}}
      {{> task}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

`Template.tasks.helpers` instead of `Template.body.helpers`.

Comment: I thought that ("body") looked o[dd,ff], but "containers" is no better; it still fails at that same line, now "Template.container.helpers({"

Comment: Yes, sorry, I totally missed that container was a class and not a template. Please see my updated answer.